# Mapping 2D Array JavaScript into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table, mapping

I have an 2D Array like this

```
[["Manchester City", 92], ["Liverpool", 82], ["Tottenham", 78], ["Chelsea", 78], ["Manchester United", 72], ["Arsenal", 69]]
```

I want to map all of the data of 2D Array into a html table, here the example of my html table code

```
<table id="codexpl">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 col 1</td>
        <td>row 1 col 2</td>
        <td>row 1 col 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 1</td>
        <td>row 2 col 2</td>
        <td>row 2 col 3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So how to solve this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table')
    , tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

createTable([["Manchester City", 92], ["Liverpool", 82], ["Tottenham", 78], ["Chelsea", 78], ["Manchester United", 72], ["Arsenal", 69]]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your array, for each top-level element, add a row to the table. Then, for each next-level element, add a cell and insert the element's contents into the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
const toTable = (arr) =>
  `<table id="codexpl">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    ${arr.map(
    (item, index) =>
      `<tr>
      <td>${index + 1}</td>
      <td>${item[0]}</td>
      <td>${item[1]}</td>
  </tr>`
  ).join('\n')}
</table>`
```

Just pass the array to it and it will return the HTML code.